# How to get if i selected spinner item, then appear specified list item with custom list view (multicolumn)?

Tags: android

how to display the listview value. I have one dropdown spinner.if i selected the spinner item, the specified list item value will be displayed in the custom listview.

//SampActivity.java

```
 class GlobalClass extends Application {
 public static List<String> myval=new ArrayList<String>();

  }
      public  class SampActivity extends Activity {
                 String[] Category={"----SELECT---- ",        "BEVERAGES","BREAKFAST","LUNCH","DINNER","DESSERTS","APPETIZERS & SIDES"};

  Spinner spinner;
   ListView l1;


   String[] item;
   int myid;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. **/
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    l1=(ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Category);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,long id) {              


  String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(Text.equals("----SELECT----")) {

    }       
    else if(Text.equals("BEVERAGES")){

       l1.setAdapter(bever);

       return;
   }    
   else if(Text.equals("BREAKFAST")){

       l1.setAdapter(Breakf);
       return;
   }
   else if(Text.equals("LUNCH")){

       l1.setAdapter(lunc);
       return;
   }
   else if(Text.equals("DINNER")){
       l1.setAdapter(Dinn);
       return;

   }
   else if(Text.equals("DESSERTS")){
       l1.setAdapter(Dessert);
       return;

   }
   else if(Text.equals("APPETIZERS & SIDES")){
       l1.setAdapter(Appet);
       return;

   }
     }


     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

              }

        });

   l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SELECTED :: " +((TextView) view).getText(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


     String st1 =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        GlobalClass.myval.add(st1);


       }
   });



}
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return StrActivity.Beverage.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text1.setText(StrActivity.Beverage[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(StrActivity.Beveragecos[position]);
        return convertView;
      }
     static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
    }
}
 }
```

//StrActivity.java

```
 package com.tru.samp;

  public class StrActivity {
    public static String[] Beverage={"PEPSI","COKE","LASSI","FALOODA","BUTTER MILK","GREEN TEA","BADAM MILK","MASALA CHAI" };
     public static String[] Beveragecos={"$ 0.5","$ 0.5","$ 2.0","$ 3.0","$ 1.5","$ 0.7","$ 0.8","$ 1.0"};
    public static String[] Breakfast={"SIRLOIN & EGG","CFS STEAK & EGG","T-BONE & EGG","TWO EGGS BREAKFAST","2EGG W/MEAT","BEL WAFFLE","BEL WAFFLE W/MEAT","BLUEBERRY CAKE","CAKES","FABULOUS FRENCH TST","MOONS","FRENCH TST"};
     public static String[] Breakfastcos={"$ 2.5","$ 3.0","$ 3.5","$ 2.7","$ 4.7","$ 3.0","$ 5.6","$ 3.0","$ 2.5","$ 3.2","$ 2.0","$ 1.0"};
     public static String[] Lunch={" CRAB CAKE SANDWICH","TUSCAN GRILLED CHICKEN PANINI","SOUTHWEST TURKEY CLUB"," LOBSTER ROLL","TUNA MELT"," FRENCH DIP","YOUR OWN SANDWICH"};
     public static String[] Lunchcos={"$ 4.0","$ 4.5","$ 7.0","$ 3.5","$ 5.5","$ 6.3","$ 5.0"};
     public static String[] Dinner={"DUBLIN BAY PRAWN","CRAB FROM BRITTANY","WHITE ASPARAGUS","BLEWIT MUSHROOM","JOHN DORY FISH","MONKFISH","VEAL SWEET BREAD","LAMB","PIGEON FRY"};
     public static String[] Dinnercos={"$ 3.5","$ 4.5","$ 3.3","$ 2.6","$ 4.3","$ 3.7","$ 2.5","$ 3.0","$ 4.0"};
     public static String[] Desserts={"ECHOURGNAC CHEESE","HAZELNUT","GARIGUETTE STRAWBERRY","MOUSSE & ZEST","APRICOT","CHOCOLATE"};
      public static String[] Dessertscos={"$ 1.0","$ 1.5","$ 2.7","$ 4.0","$ 2.9","$ 1.5"};
     public static String[] Appetizers={"Greek Artichoke Spinach","Seafood Appetizers","Tapenade Flatbread","Cranberry Blue Cheese","Fig and Blue Cheese","Sun-Dried Tomato","Tropical Crab Rangoon"};
     public static String[] Appertizerscos={"$ 1.3","$ 2.7","$ 1.5","$ 2.0","$ 2.5","$ 2.3","$ 3.0"};
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hi @CharuPriya...any update in your project??

Comment: AKASH if i am using edittext in one activity and give data in edittext,then am go to next activity and display the edittext items in textView,then come back to the previous activity the data s  are cleared.our requirement is dont clear the data in the edit text when back to prev activity

Comment: See @CharuPriya for that you have to save edittext data into some variable or say preferences and when you come back to the activity show the edittext data from prefernces in onResume() method of that activity.

Comment: please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1278/android-discussion @CharuPriya

Comment: which city you belong to @CharuPriya??

Comment: hi @CharuPriya..how are you?? and what happened to your project.is it completed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

```
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(HotelActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Category);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(Text.equals("----SELECT----")) {

            }       
            else if(Text.equals("BEVERAGES")){
                CustomAdapter bever=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Beverage.length);
                listView.setAdapter(bever);
               return;
           }    
           else if(Text.equals("BREAKFAST")){
               CustomAdapter breakfast=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Breakfast.length);
               listView.setAdapter(breakfast);
               return;
           }
           else if(Text.equals("LUNCH")){
               CustomAdapter lunch=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Lunch.length);
                listView.setAdapter(lunch);
               return;
           }
           else if(Text.equals("DINNER")){
               CustomAdapter dinner=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Dinner.length);
               listView.setAdapter(dinner);
               return;

           }
           else if(Text.equals("DESSERTS")){
               CustomAdapter dessert=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Desserts.length);
                listView.setAdapter(dessert);
               return;

           }
           else if(Text.equals("APPETIZERS & SIDES")){
               CustomAdapter app=new CustomAdapter(HotelActivity.this,pos,Appetizers.length);
                listView.setAdapter(app);
               return;

           }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        />


    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter Class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    int pos;
    int length;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public static String[] Beverage={"PEPSI","COKE","LASSI","FALOODA","BUTTER MILK","GREEN TEA","BADAM MILK","MASALA CHAI" };
    public static String[] Beveragecos={"$ 0.5","$ 0.5","$ 2.0","$ 3.0","$ 1.5","$ 0.7","$ 0.8","$ 1.0"};
   public static String[] Breakfast={"SIRLOIN & EGG","CFS STEAK & EGG","T-BONE & EGG","TWO EGGS BREAKFAST","2EGG W/MEAT","BEL WAFFLE","BEL WAFFLE W/MEAT","BLUEBERRY CAKE","CAKES","FABULOUS FRENCH TST","MOONS","FRENCH TST"};
    public static String[] Breakfastcos={"$ 2.5","$ 3.0","$ 3.5","$ 2.7","$ 4.7","$ 3.0","$ 5.6","$ 3.0","$ 2.5","$ 3.2","$ 2.0","$ 1.0"};
    public static String[] Lunch={" CRAB CAKE SANDWICH","TUSCAN GRILLED CHICKEN PANINI","SOUTHWEST TURKEY CLUB"," LOBSTER ROLL","TUNA MELT"," FRENCH DIP","YOUR OWN SANDWICH"};
    public static String[] Lunchcos={"$ 4.0","$ 4.5","$ 7.0","$ 3.5","$ 5.5","$ 6.3","$ 5.0"};
    public static String[] Dinner={"DUBLIN BAY PRAWN","CRAB FROM BRITTANY","WHITE ASPARAGUS","BLEWIT MUSHROOM","JOHN DORY FISH","MONKFISH","VEAL SWEET BREAD","LAMB","PIGEON FRY"};
    public static String[] Dinnercos={"$ 3.5","$ 4.5","$ 3.3","$ 2.6","$ 4.3","$ 3.7","$ 2.5","$ 3.0","$ 4.0"};
    public static String[] Desserts={"ECHOURGNAC CHEESE","HAZELNUT","GARIGUETTE STRAWBERRY","MOUSSE & ZEST","APRICOT","CHOCOLATE"};
     public static String[] Dessertscos={"$ 1.0","$ 1.5","$ 2.7","$ 4.0","$ 2.9","$ 1.5"};
    public static String[] Appetizers={"Greek Artichoke Spinach","Seafood Appetizers","Tapenade Flatbread","Cranberry Blue Cheese","Fig and Blue Cheese","Sun-Dried Tomato","Tropical Crab Rangoon"};
    public static String[] Appertizerscos={"$ 1.3","$ 2.7","$ 1.5","$ 2.0","$ 2.5","$ 2.3","$ 3.0"};

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int pos, int length) {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.pos=pos;
        this.length=length;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DataHolder holder=null;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder=new DataHolder();
            layoutInflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder.title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.price=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(DataHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(pos==1){
            holder.title.setText(Beverage[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Beveragecos[position]);
        }
        else if(pos==2){
            holder.title.setText(Breakfast[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Breakfastcos[position]);
        }
        else if(pos==3){
            holder.title.setText(Lunch[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Lunchcos[position]);
        }
        else if(pos==4){
            holder.title.setText(Dinner[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Dinnercos[position]);
        }
        else if(pos==5){
            holder.title.setText(Desserts[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Dessertscos[position]);
        }
        else if(pos==6){
            holder.title.setText(Appetizers[position]);
            holder.price.setText(Appertizerscos[position]);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class DataHolder{
        TextView title,price;
    }

}
```

and list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
     >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by applicationcontroller class....just make one class ApplicationController as below

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
           // write your getters and setters here....
}
```

in Applicationcontroller class, put getter and setter methods.You can set the data by set method in one activity, and get that data back by get method in the other activity of your application. This class stores the data in enitre application..Moreoevr, you have to declare that calss in manifest.xml file

```
android:name=".your package name.ApplicationController"
```

the above should be declared in application tag of manifest.xml file.....